# Erro ao consultar api criada em R com plumber

Tags: r, api, get

Amigos, criei uma api em plumber , quando faço a consulta desta api diretamente no navegador consigo visualizar os dados , porém quando faço uso da função GET() tenho o seguinte erro :

> Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width,
>   3L, :   invalid 'trim' argument

Vocês teriam alguma solução para meu problema? Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia fornecer o código do `plumber` e como está fazendo o request com o `GET()`?

Comment: Resolvi assim:        r <- GET("url", encode = 'json')
r1 <- httr::content(r, 'text'). Obrigado